# switching from  http to https  gives different errors on different browser?

Tags: php, .htaccess, browser, https, ssl-certificate

I want to run few pages on `https` while all others pages run on `http`

I wrote below code in **.htaccess** and on **config.inc.php** file

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC]

# Rewrite non www to www.charityrummage.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /do_login.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /payment/?.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

# traffic to http://, except login.php and payment.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/login|/do_login.php|/payment)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

also made some changes in **config.inc.php** which is required and first file of the website

#### config.inc.php

```
$ssl_page = array('login.php','do_login.php','payment.php');
// Note: do_login.php is intermediate page
if(in_array(trim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'/'),$ssl_page)){
    define('PROTOCOL','https://');    
 }else{
   define('PROTOCOL','http://');
}
define('DS','/');
define('URL',PROTOCOL.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].DS);
// based on URL i made CSS and JS Path
```

here is the website link :

> http://www.charityrummage.com.

login page is ssl enabled :

> https://www.charityrummage.com/login

### BUT

when I run the website, it gives different errors on different browsers  and its really annoying. below are the error description on different browsers

#### IE8

> it always prompt for security error and
>    if i click on Yes then display everything fine except left panel
>   if i click on NO then certificate error near web address but website works fine.

#### Chrome ( v :20.0.1132.8 )

> display multiple warning about css and js ( see in console ) in below format:
>
> **The page at https://www.charityrummage.com/login ran insecure content
>   from http://www.charityrummage.com/css/reset.css**
>
> but if you view source of [login page](https://www.charityrummage.com/login) then you can see that every
>   **css** and **js** running with `https://`

#### Firefox (v 16.0)

> it display lock sign ( secure ) just for few seconds and then gone away
>    ( i m surprised it never prompt security alert for https )
>   but when we go with  **page info -> media** then many of images are coming  from **http://**

Will you please examine and tell me what is exact problem?

One more thing i want to know.

> if `https://` pages are not displaying properly then which one is responsible

- Operating system OR
- Browser OR
- server OR
- Programming issue OR
- SSL certificate issue

  and  at the end what is the solution of this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that file from `https://www.charityrummage.com/css/style.css` are redirected to the `http` version. That's why you got error. When you call them directly, [it 301](http://hurl.eu/hurls/49a89af9cb2bf627dc412f9fe0718a3ec2c0876c/4d6c38deec80812a556fd149afc98ac6aec6f02c) to the non-secure version.

Comment: @j0k Thanks for help. but how to fix this?

Comment: but if you see the **page source of login** then it show `style.css` with `htps://` and you click on this then it takes you to that css

Comment: Yep, but to the non-secure version of the css. That's why you got error from all browser. You might find a rule to not redirect asset file to http when they are called from https (rule that I don't know).

Comment: Your last rule force a redirect to `http` for all url except page login and payment. So css and jpg are also redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this rule:

```
# Force files ending in X to use same protocol as initial request
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$ - [S=1]
```

or this one:

```
# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js)$ - [NC,L]
```

Before the `# traffic to http://`

Comment: +1 your second idea just remove waring from chrome, but IE8 still show certificate error and firefox also showing images from http:// link

Comment: have you cleared the firefox/ie8 cache? I'm on FF15 and all images are served via https and aren't redirected.

Comment: Can you do me a favor please. can you please send me the  complete screenshot of ie8 with lock sign. on http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 0):

I got round this problem before by setting the base href on the page like so

```
<base href="<?php echo HTTPS_BASE_REF; ?>"></base>
```

This meant that all links derived from this and resolved correctly.

The constant of HTTPS_BASE_REF was set in my config.inc.php file.